# How can I test android application for network errors?

Tags: android, networking

I have content management application that uses TCP/IP to fetch data. I would like to test this application for several network problems like packet loss and connection lost.

Is there some easy way to emulate network problems to test Android application?

In DDMS there is some connection and latency setting for device, hovewer it looks like this is not working. I can set *denied* or *unregistered* but fetching from server is untouched. I'm using Windows for development.

---

I have tried so far:

F8 - 3G icon disappears, however I'm still able to download data.

DDMS, Change of Telephony status - 3G icon disappears, however I'm still able to download data.

Settings, Mobile networks, Data enabled false - 3G icon disappears, however I'm still able to download

Airplane mode - 3G icon disappears, however I'm still able to download

Dev tools - Wifi toggle - I'm getting errors:

```
09-27 16:43:31.353: ERROR/Connectivity(518): EVENT_TOGGLE_WIFI
09-27 16:43:31.363: ERROR/WifiService(62): Failed to load Wi-Fi driver.
```

Comment: for testing the lost of internet connexion for example  , you can desactivate the 3G connection from your emulator by pressing F8. for example; launch your application , and then while downloading data, try to disable the connection by pressing F8 , and then you can see the reaction of your app

Comment: @Houcine: I think you should rewrite your comment as answer, so you can get reputation for it.

Comment: ok Jan Hudec , i will write it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

for testing the lost of internet connexion for example , you can desactivate the 3G connection from your emulator by pressing F8. for example; launch your application , and then while downloading data, try to disable the connection by pressing F8 , and then you can see the reaction of your app

Comment: If i press F8, icon of 3G disapears, however I'm able to connect to server and download data. I have tried Settings and disable mobile connect, I have tried enable airplane mode. I'm still able to download data.

Comment: if you press F8 and the icon disapears, so you can't download data it will stop . try it on a device and just after launching the download , desactive the WIFI , and see

Comment: If i press F8 before download or while downloading nothing happens. I have tried web browser just now. It showed dialog no connection to network and loaded page in background. After I closed dialog I was able to browse web. It looks like all this at emulator only changes connectivity status, but remains connected.

Comment: yes, that's why i've told you to test it on your device (if you have one) , and after just beginning the download of your data, disable the WIFI and see what will happend :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to worry about packet loss with a TCP connection given that the delivery is **reliable** (lost packets are already handled and re-sent). If you are using an emulator you can set the latency in the Telephony Status section of the Emulator Control tab in DDMS.

Comment: TCP connection is reliable... until it breaks. It guarantees order, but does not guarantee reception, because it simply can't. So if the connection times out, you never know what the other has received and what not. Depending on the particular application it may or may not be an issue (and there are many applications and protocols that got this wrong). Also for applications where latency matters, effect of packets simply taking long to arrive and occasional packet loss will be very different.

Comment: Of course. I meant that unless there is a connection timeout we can assume no loss of information with a graceful disconnection (unless there is a sneaky gremlin in the middle).

Comment: And that's exactly the trap for the unwary. You send some information and two days later the connection says it's broken. Unless the other side sent you protocol-level acknowledge that it has the information, it well may not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android [Dev Tools App](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-devtools.html).
It's by default on Emulator, and you can copy/install it on real device.

It has option (among others) to toggle Wifi periodically by some given times.

Comment: Hm, that page does not mention anything related to network or WiFi. But maybe the tool is just badly documented.

Comment: In emulator if i turn on Wifi toggle i get a huge spam of this errors:
09-27 16:43:31.353: ERROR/Connectivity(518): EVENT_TOGGLE_WIFI
09-27 16:43:31.363: ERROR/WifiService(62): Failed to load Wi-Fi driver.